# I want to install angular ag chart newly and it is showing error in my laptop

Tags: sorting, pagination, filtering, grouping, searching-xml

`your text` this is showing error in my terminal in vs-code.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\mail2\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-04-10T11_56_05_365Z-eresolve-report.txt

! A complete log of this run can be found in:
C:\Users\mail2\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-04-10T11_56_05_365Z-debug-0.log